# [FLUTTER]: Programmatically change tabs in the CustomNavigator from SecondScreen to FirstScreen

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, flutter-navigation, tabnavigator

I'm currently making an app with bottom navigator. And I have troubles with navigating from `SecondScreen` to the `FirstScreen`, programmatically, inside the SecondScreen file. But I have no idea how to do it. Because I can't have the access to the `CustomNavigatorState` part of the `CustomNavigator` class.

My **main.dart** file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './screens/custom_navigator.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
       title: 'App Name',
       home: Scaffold(
          body: CustomNavigator(),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

My **custom_navigator.dart** file, which includes `CustomNavigator` class and `_CustomNavigatorState` class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './first_second.dart';
import './second_screen.dart';
import './third_screen.dart';

import '../widgets/tab_navigator.dart';

class CustomNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CustomNavigatorState();
}

class _CustomNavigatorState extends State<CustomNavigator> {
  String _currentScreen = FirstScreen.route;
  List<String> _screenKeys = [
    FirstScreen.route,
    SecondScreen.route,
    ThirdScreen.route,
  ];
  Map<String, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> _navigatorKeys = {
    FirstScreen.route: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    SecondScreen.route: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    ThirdScreen.route: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
  };
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void changeTab(String tabItem, int index) {
    _selectedTab(tabItem, index);
  }

  void _selectedTab(String tabItem, int index) {
    if (tabItem == _currentScreen) {
      _navigatorKeys[tabItem].currentState.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _currentScreen = _screenKeys[index];
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final isFirstRouteInCurrentTab =
            !await _navigatorKeys[_currentScreen].currentState.maybePop();
        if (isFirstRouteInCurrentTab) {
          if (_currentScreen != FirstScreen.route) {
            _selectedTab(FirstScreen.route, 1);
            return false;
          }
        }
        return isFirstRouteInCurrentTab;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            _buildOffstageNavigator(FirstScreen.route),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(ScreenScreen.route),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(ThirdScreen.route),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: (index) {
            _selectedTab(_screenKeys[index], index);
          },
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'First',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Second',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Third',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildOffstageNavigator(String tabItem) {
    return Offstage(
      offstage: _currentScreen != tabItem,
      child: TabNavigator(
        navigatorKey: _navigatorKeys[tabItem],
        tabItem: tabItem,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`TabNavigator` class, where the screens added.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../screens/first_screen.dart';
import '../screens/second_screen.dart';
import '../screens/third_screen.dart';

class TabNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
  final String tabItem;

  const TabNavigator({
    Key key,
    this.navigatorKey,
    this.tabItem,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child;

    if (tabItem == FirstScreen.route) {
      child = FirstScreen();
    } else if (tabItem == SecondScreen.route) {
      child = SecondScreen();
    } else if (tabItem == ThirdScreen.route) {
      child = ThirdScreen();
    }

    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to navigate with `Navigator.push` and `Navigator.pushNamed`, but it navigates inside SecondScreen without changing the BottomNavigationTabBars.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
   MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (_) => SecondScreen(),
   ),
);
```

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondScreen.route);
```

Also I can't use Provider, because I don't have access to _CustomNavigatorState class. Could anybody offer me any decision of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have the nested `Scaffolds`, it's probably better to move your `BottomNavigationBar` to the outer `Scaffold` so you only have one `Scaffold` in your app. For the body of the outter `Scaffold` you will have your `Stack`

Regarding the navigator issues. The body of your app in a `Stack` with three offstage widgets. Only one of the widgets is visible at a time. When changing between each `Offstage` widget you don't actually navigate to it, all you have to do is change your `_currentScreen` to which ever you would like. So if you're on page one and would like to "push" to page 2 then have something like

```
onPressed: () {
    SetState(() {
        _currentScreen = FirstScreen.route;
    }
}
```

Then when your body rebuilds from the `setState` it will set the `FirstScreen` to be onstage and all other screens to be offstage. Showing you the `FirstScreen`.

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to the ```_CustomNavigatorState``` class. If I move ```_currentScreen``` to the ```CustomNavigator``` body, then I can't call ```setState``` because I change only variable. This is first. Secondly, how can I get access to the ```CustomNavigator``` class from ```SecondPage```?

Comment: You could pass a function to the SecondPage which is a setState for the _CustomNavigatorState or use a state management system such as Provider. By changing the _currentScreen variable, it will change the BottomNavigationBar's selected item and will show you the screen selected.

Comment: You will only use the Navigator.push() methods to change the route within each screen of the stack, not to navigate between the stack screens.

Comment: I tried to do as you said, but I have additional class called ```TabNavigator```, where I actually call my three Screens. Actually, the access to my screens is i that class. In ```CustomNavigator``` class I operate only with route names of my screens, without passing the instance of screens. I pass it in ```TabNavigator``` class. So I updated my question, I added ```TabNavigator``` class body. If it helps to you to get my problems:) Thanks for helping me:)

Comment: Let's say, I can change ```_currentScreen``` in ```CustomNavigation``` from every my screen. But I need to call ```setState``` for ```_CustomNavigationState``` from ```CustomNavigation``` class. So I have no idea how to reach it.

Comment: Well I found a solution, so I'm writing it here, if someone will head it in the future. Add this  ```static _CustomNavigatorState of(BuildContext context) => context.findAncestorStateOfType<_CustomNavigatorState>();``` in ```CustomNavigator``` class, than make ```_selectedTab``` from ```_CustomNavigatorState``` visible by deleting _ sign. That's it. In every Screen I programmatically change my Tabs using  ```CustomNavigator.of(context).selectedTab(FirstScreen.route, 0)```